# phpmyadmin duda con cambio en el formato de insertar registros

Tags: javascript, mysql, phpmyadmin

tengo una duda con respecto al phpmyadmin. Uso una app que programe hace un tiempo para añadir registros a una base de datos de forma mas comoda. todo funciona bien si no por algo que no entiendo. aparentemente sin razon se me cambia el modo de insertar los registros cada tanto (no sabria exactamente cada cuanto pasa esto pero a mi parecer sucede de forma aleatoria) a la siguiente forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La forma en que estoy acostumbrado a verla es la siguiente (la imagen la tome de google ya que como se cambio el formato en que subo los registros...)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto no seria un problema si no fuera que tengo que cambiar el modo en que inserto los registros... la query para insertar en la primera imagen seria algo como

```
query  = 'insert into movies (id, id_info, id_content) VALUES ('', 'ultimo id' 'ultimo id')'
```

y para insertar con la segunda imagen seria algo como

```
query = 'insert into movies (id, id_info, id_content) VALUES ('', 'ultimo id-[titulo]' 'ultimo id-[titulo]')'
```

PD: no se si tendra algo que ver... pero la base de datos esta alojada en un hosting. (hostinger)

Comment: No se si te refieres a ese select que aparece, el cual lo que indica es que hay relaciones de ese campo con otro campo de otra tabla y se muestran sus datos a escoger, porque de otra forma te daria error si te equivocaras y no pusieras el dato correctamente.

Comment: me refiero a que alterna el modo en que se selecciona las ID foraneas

Comment: Lo siento, no lo acabo de entender, es mi culpa seguramente, esperemos que otro te entienda mejor y te de respuesta. En la primera imagen, si pulsas sobre la casilla `Mostrar valores foráneos` entiendo que te muestra más o menos lo mismo que la segunda imagen, aunque lo desconozco y ahora mismo no puedo intentar reproducirlo. Suerte!

Comment: No te preocupes! Gracias por la predisposicion.

Comment: podrías intentar a explicarlo algo mejor porque no entiendo tu pregunta

Comment: tu te refieres que las claves foráneas se cambian sola?

Comment: @JavierG.Raya Me refiero a que el formato en el que se insertar las claves foraneas cambian. la imagen una muestra una forma de colocarlas y la imagen dos muestra otra distinta. lo que me perjudica a mi es el modo en que tengo que hacer la query, mientras que en la primer imagen la query solo tengo que especificar el id de cada clave foranea en la segunda imagen tengo que especificar el id y el titulo de la publicacion.

Comment: pues ni idea la verdad

Comment: Diria que eso no importa, creo que lo muestra así porque son dos columnas relacionadas a la vez, en una única relación, con otra tabla, y creo que te las muestra así para tu comodidad, pero tanto si elijes "1-Warsaw" como "Warsaw-1" el resultado final va a ser el mismo, y en la columna va a poner solo el id. Tan solo debes probarlo en el phpmyadmin y apuntarte las consultas que salen cuando lo haces y comprobar si son identicas.

Comment: @masterguru Si importa, fijate la imagen uno solo me pide un dato (id o titulo) y en la imagen dos me pide el id y el titulo, al hacer una consulta desde nodejs tengo dos formas de escribir la consulta y va variando cual funciona si la primera o la segunda.

Comment: ¿Pero lo has probado?  Es decir, ¿has probado de insertar un dato usando esa columna de la imagen dos de las dos formas posibles y has notado alguna diferencia en la consulta que genera?  Eso es lo que tienes que probar. Lo digo porque en mis tablas relacionadas tambien veo ese comportamiento y el campo es INT, por lo tanto, aunque me muestre `id-titulo` (o los campos que sean) estoy convencido que tan solo va a poner un INT (y entonces por eso digo que eso no importa, tan solo lo ponen para que sepas las relaciones que ha encontrado actualmente en la otra tabla relacionada mediante esos dos)

Comment: @masterguru sisi lo probe! la sintaxis de la query es erronea porque el formato para insertar es distinto al que tenia antes, tampoco se la razon por la cual se cambia de forma espontanea :(

Comment: @masterguru me da el siguiente error al utilizar la query2 (especificando id-[titulo]) Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
y con la query1 lo mismo

Comment: No se lo que estas haciendo realmente con esas querys... pensaba que eran ejemplo, pero si me centro en ellas veo cosas mal de sintaxis, que no sea eso simplemente.  Tu has puesto esto: `query  = 'insert into movies (id, id_info, id_content) VALUES ('', 'ultimo id' 'ultimo id')'` y si realmente eso lo ejecutas con PHP petará por todas partes. En PHP deberia ser así exactamente: `$query  = 'insert into movies (id, id_info, id_content) VALUES (\'\', \'ultimo id\', \'ultimo id\')'`.  Fíjate que estoy escapando las comilas simples internas y que agrego una coma entre los utlimo_id.

Comment: @NahuelNavarrete no estas escapando bien las cadenas de caracteres, ademas, te recomendaria que los valores que sean numericos NO los encierres dentro de comillas simples ni dentro de comillas dobles, simplemente dejalos sin comillas. lo que puedes hacer para no tener que estar escapando comillas es, si vas a usar comillas simples de la forma en la que estas usandolas entonces encierra todo dentro de comillas dobles asi: `"insert into movies (id, id_info, id_content) VALUES (null, ultimo id, ultimo_id)"`

Comment: No se si usas `mysqli` o `PDO`, pero independientemente de lo que estes usando no estas pasando valores correctos, pues lo que intentas pasarle a la consulta no es una variable si lo pones tal cual lo tienes ahi.